# Why my linux buffer is too small to dump 'ip a' output?

Tags: linux, docker

I have an environment with docker containers and when I try to execute:

```
ip a
```

inside one container, I get the output:

```
Error: Buffer too small for object.
Dump terminated
```

Any idea why this is happening? And more important: how to increase the buffer so that I can get the correct output? My host and containers are running linux.

Comment: Can you run the command on the host and using other images? What image gives you issues? What host environment are you running on?

Comment: Same problem with ubuntu and opensuse

Comment: Is that the host or container environment? Are you unable to answer the other questions?